# How to use multibyte file names in adb shell?

Tags: adb, shell, mksh

I have a Galaxy S6 running Android 7.0:

```
zeroflte:/ $ getprop ro.build.version.release                                
7.0
```

There exists a file which uses the Unicode codepoint `U+1F308` (`RAINBOW`) in its name:

```
zeroflte:/ $ ls -al /sdcard/tmp
total 1024
drwxrwx--x  5 root sdcard_rw 4096 2020-07-09 05:44 .
drwxrwx--x 49 root sdcard_rw 4096 2020-06-25 07:27 ..
-rw-rw----  1 root sdcard_rw   17 2018-04-25 20:47 123.org
drwxrwx--x  2 root sdcard_rw 4096 2020-07-09 05:54 crypt
-rw-rw----  1 root sdcard_rw    9 2020-07-08 13:26 .gpx
zeroflte:/ $
```

However, I have no idea how to use this file name in an adb shell command. I would like to apply `ls -1 -d -l /sdcard/tmp/\.gpx` or similar, but I cannot enter the `RAINBOW` char. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: What about `ls -1dl /sdcard/tmp/*.gpx`? Or rename the file to remove special character.

Comment: Did you try `Alt + ` or `Ctrl + Shift + U` or whatever key combination applicable to your OS for entering unicode characters?

Comment: I don't need it interactively. I'm the author of Emacs' Tramp package, which uses `adb shell` to access files on Android devices. So I need something which could be used in a script.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. `zeroflte:/ $ ls -dl1 /sdcard/tmp/$(printf '\U0001f308').gpx
ls: /sdcard/tmp/\U0001f308.gpx: No such file or directory`

Comment: Don't know. How do I get this string?

Comment: My bad. Due to different path it was using my GNU `printf` binary. Let's ask MKSH developer about unicode escape sequence if it's supported. @mirabilos sir your help needed.

Comment: Maybe with `sed`?  I believe it's part of busybox and it supports escaping unicode.  Also,  don't you want `\uD83C\uDF08` and not `\u0001F308` ?

Comment: It doesn't work. `echo x | sed -re s/x/\x01\xF3\x08/g` results in `x01xF3x08`

Comment: Can you use the inode reference to do the renaming?  Or do you have to work on arbitrary indexes?

Comment: All I know are the file names. The multibyte file name could also be the target of the rename, where an inode number wouldn't help at all. As said, I need it for scripted access via adb shell, from inside Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

`mksh` developer here.

`mksh` uses UTF-8 internally, but is currently limited to the BMP (basic multilingua plane), which means U+0000 to U+FFFD. If you want to use SMP codepoints (U-00010000 to U-0010FFFD) on the input line, you currently have to *dis*able the UTF-8 mode (sorry):

```
$ set +U
```

That switches to a byte-wise mode which does not limit the input. (You can tab-complete files with SMP characters in them, but not directly input them, because input is validated.)

```
$ set -U   # switches back to UTF-8 mode
```

Switching mksh to full 21-bit Unicode is already on my TODO, and I’m currently hoping to be able to provide it for the next release.

Comment: Thanks, I've added your comment to Tramp. ATM I'm doing some workaround, executing the command in question via `adb shell <command>`.